# Is "mediaeval" an outdated spelling of "medieval"?

Tags: orthography, contemporary-english

I saw "mediaeval" on a Wikipedia page, and figuring it was a typo, edited it to "medieval", [it was reverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=The_Bird_in_Borrowed_Feathers&oldid=prev&diff=849913557&diffmode=source) as apparently mediaeval is the UK spelling. However, in all the dictionaries I've found from a quick peruse, including those of the UK, they now prefer the medieval spelling.

Is mediaeval still preferred anywhere officially, or is it completely outdated?

Resources I found:

- Oxford Dictionary Online (a UK dictionary) redirects [mediaeval](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mediaeval) to [medieval](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/medieval)
- [Wikitionary includes stats on it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:mediaeval)
- [An old argument on Wikipedia about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Middle_Ages/British_spelling_of_Medieval)

Comment: I may be outdated but I would not dream of spelling these words with "e"  rather than "ae".  Seriously, my point is that educated BrE native speakers still use these spellings and associate the newer versions with North America.

Comment: No. It's an optional, and to many users clearly more correct spelling. That doesn't make it outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

([Routledge 2016](https://www.routledge.com/The-Routledge-Handbook-of-the-English-Writing-System-1st-Edition/Cook-Ryan/p/book/9780415715973) p.121) suggests that spellings using the ae digraph are still favored in some words but are gradually being simplified. The spelling can be simplified because there is no pronunciation difference: the ai/ae diphthong was monophthonged in English hundreds of years ago.

English spelling has many quirks inherited from orthographers who insisted on spellings that reflected origins of words rather than actual pronunciation. See ([Algeo & Butcher 2013](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9781133307273) p.162). Some spellings even introduced letters that weren't pronounced at the time, such as the “l” in “palm” or “falcon”, that have since become spelling pronunciations.

In the case of mediaeval it seems plausible that the spelling was chosen to reflect the Latin original ***med***ium **ae**vum (middle age).

Comment: While I agree about *falcon* (/ˈfælkən/? /ˈfɒlkən/?)There isn't a pronounced *l* in *palm*; it's pronounced /pɑːm/ where I come from.

Comment: Merriam-Webster suggests you might pronounce the L in [palm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palm) and [palmistry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palmistry); it's an alternative at least in the US. "Palmistry" seems more probable to me than "palm" but I won't argue.

Answer (score -1):

The 'a' is now commonly dropped in English spelling which reflects the increased dominance of American pronunciation.  In traditional English the word contains an 'ae' sound, so using 'ae' is appropriate. In American English the sound is pronounced as 'evil', hence the unfortunate development in pronunciation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is an "ae" sound? The IPA /æ/?

Comment: Traditional English surely used æsc (æ) rather than ae?